# Use LLDB to debug whill make xcode Noresponding

Tags: xcode, lldb, xcode5

When I use LLDB on Xcode 4.6 to debug my program ,the app will be no responding and when I use GDB it is OK,
but In the new Xcode 5 there is only LLDB can be used 
who can tell me how can I fix my LLDB or reinstall it?
thx

Comment: I had updated the Xcode5 pd6 and the lldb is still can't used who can help me?!

Comment: Did you get an error message? Please post the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this procedure**

Remove old versions of Xcode
Upgrade to Xcode 5.0.1

NOTE: GDB is no longer supported. LLDB will be installed automatically.

Please use a compatible version of OSX (10.9, Mavericks).

If this answer helps please click the checkmark to accept the answer.